# Getting unique values and their count in a ruby 2-d array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have a Ruby 2D Array, where each array has a row from a SQL query and its columns inside the subarray.

```
@mastertest = connection.execute("select code_ver from mastertest")
```

which might contain something like this:

```
@mastertest = [{"abc"} , {"abc"}, {"pqr"}, {"xyz"}, {"pqr"}, {"pqr"}]
```

Now, I want to form another 2D array which would give me just the rows which have a unique value of `code_ver` with their count.

Something like this:

```
@result = [{"abc", 2} , {"xyz", 1} , {"pqr", 3}]
```

Comment: Those are not valid Ruby objects.

Comment: This question is rather confusing... could you please explain better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@result = @mastertest.inject(Hash.new(0)) { |hash,element|
  hash[element] +=1
  hash
}
```

Answer (score 3):

I think `each_with_object` is better way:

```
["abc" , "abc", "pqr", "xyz", "pqr", "pqr"].each_with_object({}) do |e, o|
  o[e] ||= 0
  o[e] += 1
end.to_a
#=> [["xyz", 1], ["abc", 2], ["pqr", 3]]
```

Comment: Why would be `each_with_object` a better way?

Comment: It's more nature, less prone to make mistakes, and less code.
http://www.themomorohoax.com/2009/01/03/rails-each-with-object-vs-inject

Comment: You are telling me that it is better for some reason you don't even use since you return the array at the end of the loop while you don't need to?

Comment: I am sorry I made that mistake, I have updated it. Thanks for your suggestion.
By the way, this method is 1.9.1 and later version.
http://apidock.com/ruby/v1_9_3_125/Enumerator/each_with_object

Comment: The code is working fine in `Ruby 1.8.7`/`Rails 2.3.11` ;)

Comment: It can't work in Ruby 1.8.7 only.

Comment: This question is great, too bad I can't submit an answer. But I think you can also use tap.    a = ["abc" , "abc", "pqr", "xyz", "pqr", "pqr"]
   {}.tap do |o|
     a.each do |e|
       o[e] ||= 0
       o[e] += 1
     end
   end.to_a

Answer (score 2):

As Sawa said, your data are not valid Ruby objects. I assume you meant:

```
@mastertest = ["abc" , "abc", "pqr", "xyz", "pqr", "pqr"]
@result = @mastertest.inject({}) do |a, e|
  a[e] ||= 0
  a[e] += 1
  a
end.to_a
#=> [["xyz", 1], ["abc", 2], ["pqr", 3]]
```